# JQuery function not calling

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have got the below code to get the ID's of all selected items of a list. This code worked for me when I used it for other list but now when I am using for another list, this code is not getting the ID values.

```
 $(".ms-listviewtable tbody[selectablerows == ''] tr").each(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row);

            if ($row.find("td[class*='ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell']").children('div.s4-itm-cbx.s4-itm-imgCbx').attr("aria-checked")=="true")
            {


                $selected = $row.find("td[class*='ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell']").children('div.s4-itm-cbx.s4-itm-imgCbx');
                $Contextid = $selected.context.id;
                $id = $Contextid.slice($Contextid.indexOf(',') + 1, $Contextid.lastIndexOf(','));
                alert($id);

                    array[idCount]=$id;
                    idCount=idCount+1;
}           
        });
```

it shows error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   .ms-listviewtable tbody[selectablerows == ''] tr

while debugging it only shows that the array value is 0. But if I select two items, it should show me the ID's of both the list items.

HTML Code- http://jsfiddle.net/mag4zj0v/

Comment: can you post the related html?

Comment: It is for a sharepoint list

Comment: while debugging in browser it shows error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .ms-listviewtable tbody[selectablerows == ''] tr"

Comment: you can take the html from browser

Comment: Html for the whole list would be too big from the browser, which part should I post?

Comment: just take the html under this `.ms-listviewtable tbody[selectablerows == ''] tr` selector. If it is still big then paste in jsbin or jsfiddle and then give the link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ms-listviewtable tbody[selectablerows != ''] tr").each(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row);

            if ($row.find("td[class*='ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell']").children('div.s4-itm-cbx.s4-itm-imgCbx').attr("aria-checked")=="true")
            {


                $selected = $row.find("td[class*='ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell']").children('div.s4-itm-cbx.s4-itm-imgCbx');
                $Contextid = $selected.context.id;
                $id = $Contextid.slice($Contextid.indexOf(',') + 1, $Contextid.lastIndexOf(','));
                alert($id);

}           
        });
```

This worked for me, I dont knw why it worked with same `==` for other site and in this site it worked with `!=`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your selector is actually incorrect.

```
tbody[selectablerows == '']
```

Should be

```
tbody[selectablerows = '']
```

See the following reference about jQuery selectors [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)